# Check differentiability of $(x,y)$ at $(0,0)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Check differentiability of $f(x,y)$ at $(0,0)$ : $f(x,y)= \frac {xy} {\sqrt {x^2 +y^2}}$ when $(x,y)\neq 0$ and $0$ when $(x,y) = 0$. What definition shall I use?

Comment: How many do you think are there? As far as I know there's just one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that both partial derivatives of first order at $\;(0,0)\;$ exist and equal zero, and besides:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\frac{y\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-\frac{x^2y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}}\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}0\;\;\text{(why?)}$$

so the partial derivatives exist and are continuous at the origin...thus the function is differentiable there.

Now fill up what's needed in the above.

Comment: I thought I missed some definitions but I made a mistake in calculations. Nevertheless, thanks for solution.

Comment: Actually I read once again what you wrote and limit of that partial derivative isn’t 0.

Comment: You're right, it isn't. I completely ommited the $\;3/2\;$ and saw an inexistent exponent $\;1/2\;$ ... In fact, the limit doesn't even exists.